# How to package my JavaScript library code with webpack as extensible as jQuery?

Tags: javascript, webpack

How to package my JavaScript library code with `webpack` as extensible as jQuery?

For example,
Sometimes, I only need `jquery`,
So, I use it as bellow,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

But, sometimes, I need some extra features (such as Draggable), so I add `jquery-ui` to my page,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Now, I use output.library to package my code as JavaScript library, but I want to package my javascript library code as this.
Some commonly used are packaged in, and some less used are added when use in the project as above.

Comment: Now I use [library-extend-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/kingller/library-extend-webpack-plugin) to do this.